# What is the correct term for this electricity device type?

Tags: vocabulary

Not sure how to phrase the question so, please, feel free to edit. Preferably without biting my head off.   :)

I'm looking for the (technically) correct term to describe the box that delivers electricity to a home or workplace.

I've found "*fuse box*" and "*electricity plant*" but those are not quite correct. I'm looking for the correct name describing the boxy thingy that (formerly) had a rotating disc counting the kilowatt consumption, the reading of which is used for invoicing.

If there's a difference, I'd prefer US version but it's definitely not a requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of these...

[image: Electricity meter]

...is an [**electricity meter**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_meter). It appears to be the same in the US as well as the UK.

[[Image source]](http://www.smartofthehome.com/2013/09/dumb-meters-pulses/)

Comment: +1, but the whole panel might be called a _distribution board_.

Comment: +1 This is **precisely** what I'm looking for. And I can't believe it was **that** easy. Is there perhaps another name for the contraption as well? Something more technical and formal?

Comment: You might call it an *inductive meter* or *induction meter* as it uses induction to turn the disc which turns the dials, but normally no: it's just a meter.

Comment: In the US, it is much more commonly called [**electric meter**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=electric+meter%2Celectricity+meter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Celectric%20meter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celectricity%20meter%3B%2Cc0)